# Cannot install tcpreplay 3.4.4

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install Tcpreplay 3.4.4 on my server that is running RHEL 5.6 and has libpcap1.1.1 installed. When I ran "./configure", it stopped at

```
checking for libpcap... /usr/local
checking for library containing pcap_close... no
configure: error: Unable to link libpcap in /usr/local
```

How to I resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Install `libnl-devel`.

There is a hard coded requirement for `libnl` in the configure file that throws:

```
checking for libpcap... /usr/local
checking for library containing pcap_close... no
configure: error: Unable to link libpcap in /usr/local
```

Or in my case:

```
checking for libpcap... /usr
checking for library containing pcap_close... no
configure: error: Unable to link libpcap in /usr
```

Comment: libnl-1_1-devel on OpenSUSE 12.3 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue myself, not on RHEL but on a white box derivative of it, but just worked out a way around it: The problem was an earlier version of libpcap bundled with tcpdump.

Do:

> tcpdump -h

And you might see something like:

> tcpdump version 3.xxx 
>   libpcap version 0.9.xxx

Which would prove whether that is your issue or not.

I guess you downloaded and compiled libpcap1.1.1, so take that back out first:

> cd libpcap-1.1.1
>   make uninstall

Next take out your existing tcpdump using whatever your package tool is, eg.:

> yum remove tcpdump
>   rpm -e tcpdump

Now put your new libpcap back

> cd libpcap-1.1.1
>   ./configure
>   make
>   make install

You probably want to get a new [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/#old-releases), so download and untar tcpdump-4.1.1.tar.gz and compile it...

> tar -zxvf tcpdump-4.1.1.tar.gz
>   cd tcpdump-4.1.1
>   ./configure
>   make
>   make install

Hope that fixes it for you!

And finally, go ahead and compile your new tcpreplay:

> cd  tcpreplay 3.4.4
>   ./configure
>   make
>   make install

Hope that does the trick for you!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
./configure LDFLAGS=-ldag
```

I have a DAG card installed in my server, and some of the test scripts that tcpreplay's configure script was trying to compile were failing on dag_*() methods.